# Pattern matching - spark scala RDD

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching, rdd

I am new to Spark and Scala coming from R background.After a few transformations of RDD, I get a RDD of type

```
Description: RDD[(String, Int)]
```

Now I want to apply a Regular expression on the String RDD and extract substrings from the String and add just substring in a new coloumn.

Input Data :

```
BMW 1er Model,278
MINI Cooper Model,248
```

Output I am looking for :

```
   Input                  |  Brand   | Series      
BMW 1er Model,278,          BMW ,        1er        
MINI Cooper Model ,248      MINI ,      Cooper
```

where Brand and Series are newly calculated substrings from String RDD

What I have done so far.

I could achieve this for a String using regular expression, but I cani apply fro all lines.

```
 val brandRegEx = """^.*[Bb][Mm][Ww]+|.[Mm][Ii][Nn][Ii]+.*$""".r //to look for BMW or MINI
```

Then I can use

```
brandRegEx.findFirstIn("hello this mini is bmW testing")
```

But how can I use it for all the lines of RDD and to apply different regular expression to achieve the output as above.

I read about this code snippet, but not sure how to put it altogether.

```
val brandRegEx = """^.*[Bb][Mm][Ww]+|.[Mm][Ii][Nn][Ii]+.*$""".r

def getBrand(Col4: String) : String = Col4 match {
    case brandRegEx(str)  =>  
    case _ => ""
    return 'substring
}
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Could elaborate what is exactly the question here? Regular expressions, pattern matching or RDD transformations?

Comment: @zero323 : Sorry if the question is not readable. Basically I want to do Pattern matching in a string using regular expressions. This is in Spark-scala RDD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To apply your regex to each item in the RDD, you should use the RDD `map` function, which transforms each row in the RDD using some function (in this case, a Partial Function in order to extract to two parts of the tuple which makes up each row):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object Example extends App {

  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example"))

  val data = Seq(
    ("BMW 1er Model",278),
    ("MINI Cooper Model",248))

  val dataRDD = sc.parallelize(data)

  val processedRDD = dataRDD.map{
    case (inString, inInt) =>
      val brandRegEx = """^.*[Bb][Mm][Ww]+|.[Mm][Ii][Nn][Ii]+.*$""".r
      val brand = brandRegEx.findFirstIn(inString)
      //val seriesRegEx = ...
      //val series = seriesRegEx.findFirstIn(inString)
      val series = "foo"
      (inString, inInt, brand, series)
  }

  processedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
  sc.stop()
}
```

Note that I think you have some problems in your regular expression, and you also need a regular expression for finding the series. This code outputs:

```
(BMW 1er Model,278,BMW,foo)
(MINI Cooper Model,248,NOT FOUND,foo)
```

But if you correct your regexes for your needs, this is how you can apply them to each row.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I also approached the same way. and i see my regular expression is not correct. I will try to correct it and post my solution here.

Comment: using `findFirstIn(inString)` I am not able to get just the substring that I need. ex: if my input string is **Model BMW 5series**. `findFirstIn(inString)` returns me also the prefix also "Model BMW". could you tell me which function to use. findFirstIn definitely  doesn't give the just Substring

Comment: Look atmy example code, it does extract the substring, e.g. "BMW". Also note that "Model BMW" is in fact a substring, just not the substring you want. The problem is with your regex not being specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

hi I was just looking for aother question and got this question. The above problem can be done using normal transformations.

```
val a=sc.parallelize(collection)
a.map{case (x,y)=>(x.split (" ")(0)+" "+x.split(" ")(1))}.collect
```